# Maven dependency aliasing

Tags: maven

I've just noted that my war contains both `woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar` and `woodstox-core-5.0.2.jar`.  They are two different version of the same library, but the library changed both groupId and artifactId.  Furthermore both are included in my war as transitive dependencies by two different modules of my project.

I know that I can use `exclusions` to remove the old version of the library but in this case I should also explicitly "include" the new version in case that module would be used alone (that is not with the other one that includes `woodstox-core-5.0.2.jar`).

I don't like this solution.  Is there any way to declare that `woodstox-core` is an alias of `woodstox-core-asl` so that Maven includes only one of these jars?

A similar problem affects old Spring 2.x that published both an all-in-one artifact and smaller separated artifacts.  However I think that the most common issue is the one related to artifacts that change their groupId and/or artifactId.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this. Maven doesn't understand the concept of aliases. If it did, then that would open the door to a whole other kind of dependency hell.

What you've described -- adding an `<exclusion/>` for the `<dependency/>` for all dependencies that need it and then explicitly adding a new `<dependency/>` for the renamed artifact -- is the only way you can achieve this at the moment.

Comment: I've found a Maven guide about artifact relocation: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html but it describe a procedure for the publisher of the artifact, not for users.  I guess that Woodstox authors haven't followed it.

Comment: Maven artifact relocation is a different thing. It's used when you decide you no longer want to use the same artifact coordinates for your library. You can change the `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version` and a few other artifact coordinates. This is meant for you as the owner and deployer of the library to do on the server side. If you're a developer just using the library and to you this is a third-party artifact, then you can't use it in the sense of "aliasing" that you're looking for.